# How can i get image to some imageView, which is in another Viewcontroller, and wasn't created(is nil) yet

Tags: swift

How can i get image to some imageView, which is in another Viewcontroller, and wasn't created(is nil) yet

```
let vc = SelectedCellViewController()
vc.nameLabel.text = MainViewController.dishesArray[indexPath.section].name
```

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an
>   Optional value

Comment: In the above code you aren't using `imageView` anywhere.

Comment: sorry, instead of imageview, i need textfield.text

Comment: Also, no `textfield` in the above code.

Comment: I use, I am creating vc which is equal any ViewController, which has label, and i want to change that label's text

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable `name` and set that variable while creating the instance of `SelectedCellViewController`. Set the `text` to `nameLabel` in `viewDidLoad()`.

```
class SelectedCellViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    var name: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.nameLabel.text = self.name
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectedCellViewController") as? SelectedCellViewController {
    vc.name = MainViewController.dishesArray[indexPath.section].name
}
```